# Remote Host Access plugin is missing in RubyMine... but where is it?

Tags: rubymine

Today my RubyMine is broken. No idea why, I didn't change anything explicitly, but my WSL Rubies are all gone. When I try to re-add them I get this:

[image]

But there's no such plug in:

[image]
[image]

What's going on? How do I fix it?

Comment: Could you check whether the following solution helps:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20288/Cant-add-remote-Ruby-interpreter.#focus=Comments-27-5591560.0-0

You might need to change the path according to your version/IDE name.

Comment: @Olivia: yes, that worked. I had to adapt it for Windows. On windows there are two JetBrain folders, one in AppData/Local and one in AppData/Roaming. It's the later one that contains this file. Do you want to add the answer to the question so I can accept it? (happy to adapt the paths to Windows after you added it).

Answer (score 0):

There's a known problem, for which you can try the following workaround:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20288/Cant-add-remote-Ruby-interpreter.#focus=Comments-27-5591560.0-0
You might need to change the path according to your version/IDE name.